# Disable button using input textbox id

Tags: angular

I have below angular code

```
 <input id="orgNm" #orgName type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Add new organization">
 <button class="addBtn" (click)="save(orgName,0)" [attr.disabled]="!orgNm"></button>
```

I want to enable disable button using input id, i tried both orgNm and orgName, but its not updating the disable property.

I don't want to use form or any function no change, any kind of ts reference i dont want to use

Please advise
Thanks

Comment: can you try with [disabled] instead of [attr.disabled]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input (change)="orgname.value = $event.target.value" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Add new organization" #orgname>
<button class="addBtn" (click)="save(orgName,0)" [disabled]="!orgname.value">add</button>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hm3pvj)

Comment: This is a good solution I think. Only it won't update in real-time using `(change)`. Switch to `(input)` instead and you will have live feedback on the button :) Forked your stackbitz and showed my idea.

Comment: I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding  `[(ngModel)]="orgNm"`

Like this:

```
<input id="orgNm" #orgName type="text" maxlength="50" [(ngModel)]="orgNm" placeholder="Add new organization">
<button class="addBtn" (click)="save(orgName,0)" [disabled]="!orgNm">Add</button>
```

Comment: I don't want to use any reference of ts file

Comment: Acrtually template reference variable `#orgName` doesn't work without setting `ngModel`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get completely what you mean, but perhaps this could work for you? (If I'm getting this question right).

```
     <input #orgName 
       type="text" 
       maxlength="50" 
       placeholder="Add new organization" 
       (input)="orgName.value = $event.target.value">

    <button class="addBtn" 
      (click)="save(orgName,0)" 
      [disabled]="!orgName.value">submit</button>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grvh3e